# Test Class Data Setup - Cant Access Data outside

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, failing-tests, test-setup

Within my test class's "setup()" method, I am calling a class that creates and inserts Salesforce objects and the necessary related objects to create that object (if any).

```
@TestSetup
static void setup() {
    Invoice__c inv = TestDataFactory.createInvoiceWithRelatedObjects();
}
```

When I "Run All Tests" this class passes no problem, and I can even debug and see the values and objects getting inserted.

When initiating a deployment from one environment to another we get the error `List index out of bounds: 0` on `Id iliId = iliList[0].Id;` :

```
List<Invoice__c> inv = [SELECT Id FROM Invoice__c];
    List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> iliList = [SELECT Id FROM Invoice_Line_Item__c];   

    Validation_Result__c validateResult = new Validation_Result__c();
    Id iliId = iliList[0].Id;
    validateResult.Invoice_Line_Item__c = iliId;
    validateResult.Invoice__c = inv[0].Id;
    validateResult.Bypass_Validation_Proceed_for_Billing__c = false;
    insert validateResult;
```

Why would test in VSCode and Developer Console not show the errors I am receiving from trying to deploy?

Here is the rest of the code in TestDataFactory.createInvoiceWithRelatedObjects()

```
public static Invoice__c createInvoiceWithRelatedObjects() {
    //Create Accounts
    Account clientAcc = createAccounts(1,'Customer_Account')[0];
    clientAcc.Pharmacy_Discount_Rate__c = 15;
    clientAcc.PaydHealth_Contracted_Rate__c = 30;
    insert clientAcc;

    Account afpAcc = createAccounts(1,'Alternate_Funding_Program')[0];
    insert afpAcc;

    Account pharmAcc = createAccounts(1,'Pharmacy')[0];
    insert pharmAcc;

    //Create Contacts
    Contact memCon = createContacts(1,'Program_Participant')[0];
    memCon.AccountId = clientAcc.Id;
    insert memCon;

    Contact presCon = createContacts(1,'Prescriber')[0];
    insert presCon;

    Drug__c drug = createDrugs(1)[0];
    insert drug;

    NDC__c ndc = createNDCs(1)[0];
    ndc.Drug__c = drug.Id;
    ndc.WAC_Unit__c = 10;
    insert ndc;

    Drug_Program__c dp = createDrugChecklists(1,'Extended_Drug_Checklist')[0];
    dp.Program__c = afpAcc.Id;
    dp.Drug__c = drug.Id;
    insert dp;

    Referral__c ref = createReferrals(1)[0];
    ref.Pharmacy__c = pharmAcc.Id;
    ref.Prescriber__c = presCon.Id;
    ref.Program_Participant__c = memCon.Id;
    ref.Program__c = afpAcc.Id;
    ref.Drug_NDC__c = ndc.Id;
    ref.Alternate_Funding_Program__c = dp.Id;
    ref.Enrollee_Amount__c = 5;
    ref.Plan_Amount__c = 0;
    ref.Alternate_Funding_Amount__c = 301;
    ref.Quantity_Received__c = 30;
    ref.Quantity__c = 30;
    insert ref;

    Alternate_Funding_Line__c afl = createAFLs(1,'Extended_Funding')[0];
    afl.Referral__c = ref.Id;
    insert afl;

    ref.Current_Alternate_Funding_Line__c = afl.Id;

    if(Schema.sObjectType.Referral__c.isUpdateable()) {
        update ref;
    }

    Dispense__c disp = createDispenses(1,'Dispense')[0];
    disp.Quantity_Received__c = 1;
    disp.Referral__c = ref.Id;
    disp.Verification_Date__c = System.today();
    disp.Verification_Info_Provider__c = 'Pharmacy';
    disp.Verification_Provider_Name__c = 'Pharmacy';
    disp.Alternate_Funding_Line_Used__c = afl.Id;
    disp.Override_Amount__c = 200;
    disp.Pharmacy_Discount_Rate__c = 0;
    disp.AWP_at_Dispense_Date__c = 100;
    disp.Alternate_Funding_Amount__c = 80;
    disp.Enrollee_Amount__c = 10;
    disp.Plan_Amount__c = 10;
    disp.PaydHealth_Share__c = 112;
    disp.PaydHealth_Share_Amount__c = 102;
    disp.Drug_NDC__c = ndc.Id;
    insert disp;

    Invoice__c inv = createInvoices(1)[0];
    inv.Account__c = clientAcc.Id;
    inv.Start_Date_Selection__c = System.today();
    inv.End_Date_Selection__c = System.today();
    inv.Email_recipients__c = 'sometestemail@uifaile.com';
    inv.Body__c = 'Test Emails';
    inv.Status__c = 'Draft';
    insert inv;

    List<Dispense__c> dispensesInAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Account_ID__c, Referral__c, Verification_Date__c FROM Dispense__c WHERE Account_ID__c =: inv.Account__c];

    List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> iliList = new List<Invoice_Line_Item__c>();

    for(Integer i = 0; i < dispensesInAccounts.size(); i++) {
        Invoice_Line_Item__c ili = new Invoice_Line_Item__c();
        ili.Name = 'Test Line Item ' + i;
        ili.Dispense_Name__c = dispensesInAccounts[i].Id;
        ili.Referral_Name__c = dispensesInAccounts[i].Referral__c;
        ili.Invoice__c = inv.Id;
        ili.Bypass_test_and_Proceed_for_Billing__c = false;
        iliList.add(ili);
    }
    if (Schema.sObjectType.Invoice_Line_Item__c.isCreateable()) {
        insert iliList;
    }
    

    return inv;
}
```

And here is the testMethod1() where the error is coming from:

```
@isTest
static void testMethod1() {
    List<Invoice__c> inv = [SELECT Id FROM Invoice__c];
    List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> iliList = [SELECT Id FROM Invoice_Line_Item__c];   

    //Insert Validation Results for Invoice
    Validation_Result__c validateResult = new Validation_Result__c();
    Id iliId = iliList[0].Id;
    validateResult.Invoice_Line_Item__c = iliId;
    validateResult.Invoice__c = inv[0].Id;
    validateResult.Bypass_Validation_Proceed_for_Billing__c = false;
    insert validateResult;

    //Get Account Id
    List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
    accountList = InvoiceGenerationController.fetchAccounts(System.today(), System.today());
    System.assertEquals(1, accountList.size(), 'One Account fetched');
    List<Id> selectedAccountIds = new List<Id>();
    for (Account a : accountList) {
        selectedAccountIds.add(a.Id);
    }

    //Get Invoice Id
    List<Invoice__c> invoiceList = new List<Invoice__c>();
    invoiceList = InvoiceGenerationController.selectedAccountsResult(selectedAccountIds, System.today(), System.today());
    System.assertEquals(1, invoiceList.size(), 'One Invoice generated');
    List<Id> selectedInvoicesId = new List<Id>();
    for (Invoice__c i : invoiceList) {
        selectedInvoicesId.add(i.Id);
    }

    //Get Invoice Line Item
    List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> invoiceLIList = new List<Invoice_Line_Item__c>();
    invoiceLIList = [SELECT Id FROM Invoice_Line_Item__c WHERE Invoice__c IN :invoiceList];
    System.assertEquals(1, invoiceLIList.size(), 'Invoice Line Items Inserted');

    //Validate Invoice
    InvoiceGenerationController.validateInvoices(selectedInvoicesId, System.today(), System.today());
    List<Validation_Result__c> vrPass = new List<Validation_Result__c>();
    List<Validation_Result__c> vrFail = new List<Validation_Result__c>();
    vrFail = [SELECT Id FROM Validation_Result__c WHERE Status__c = 'Failed'];
    vrPass = [SELECT Id FROM Validation_Result__c WHERE Status__c = 'Passed' OR Status__c = 'NA' ];
    System.assertEquals(7, vrFail.size(), 'Vr Failed');
    System.assertEquals(10, vrPass.size(), 'Vr Passed');

    InvoiceGenerationController.validateInvoiceRecord(invoiceList[0].Id);
    vrFail = new List<Validation_Result__c>();
    vrPass = new List<Validation_Result__c>();
    vrFail = [SELECT Id FROM Validation_Result__c WHERE Status__c = 'Failed'];
    vrPass = [SELECT Id FROM Validation_Result__c WHERE Status__c = 'Passed' OR Status__c = 'NA' ];
    System.assertEquals(7, vrFail.size(), 'Vr Failed');
    System.assertEquals(10, vrPass.size(), 'Vr Passed');
}
```

If any more context is needed, I am happy to provide. Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I would find `items` to be a much more readable variable name than `iliList`.

Comment: I think that seeing more of your test class is going to be important. At the very least, seeing the entire test method that's failing (including the `@isTest` and method definition). It'll also probably help to see the code of `TestDataFactory.createInvoiceWithRelatedObjects()`. As is, about the only thing I can think of is that `createInvoiceWithRelatedObjects()` is currently empty in your target org. Double check to make sure that you're deploying the tests along with the SUT (System Under Test, i.e. the thing your test is testing).

Comment: (1) `TestDataFactory.createInvoiceWithRelatedObjects()` may be silently eating DML errors in PROD; (2) Sharing rules are different in PROD than sandbox for `Invoice__c` for the test's running user

Comment: @DerekF I have provided the classes code, thanks for the feedback

Comment: any chance the running user doesn't have FLS in the target org on `Dispense__c.Account_id__c` (or any field that the formula field references?)

Answer (score 0):

(1) I noticed that you are querying the **Dispense__c** Object with the following code:

```
List<Dispense__c> dispensesInAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Account_ID__c, Referral__c, Verification_Date__c FROM Dispense__c WHERE Account_ID__c =: inv.Account__c];
```

After that, you are inserting new Invoice_Line_Item__c records based on the size of the `dispensesInAccounts` list. However, I noticed that the `Account_ID__c` field is not being populated while creating the **Dispense__c** Object record `disp`.

(2) could you check the **Invoice_Line_Item__c** Object access in the target environment for the person who is deploying?

Comment: Thanks for your response!

(1) Account_ID__c on the Dispense__c object is a formula field that gets its value from the Account.

(2) The person deploying has full Admin access.